# extjs-all-debug updateIndexes Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined

Tags: extjs4

Under Extjs 4, by repeatedly expanding and collapsing nodes or subtrees of a tree panel,
some having children, some not,
I end up getting the following error
    Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined
issued by ext-all-debug from method 'updateIndexes'.
Did anyone come across it ? Thanks.
D.

Comment: I am having the exact same error.  How did you solve it?